# How do I force vsftpd to log the numeric IP address on connection attempts?

Tags: dns, rsyslog, vsftpd, fail2ban

Scanning through my log files, I see repeated unauthorized attempts to log in to my FTP server. The system uses rDNS to give me a hostname of the remote user, and if rDNS gives an answer — even a hostname in a non-existent TLD! — then it does not log the numeric IP address. I am trying to set up `fail2ban` to jail the IP, but I can't jail (for example) `hn.kd.ny.adsl` because it doesn't exist. (Also, there is the obvious possibility of mischief if someone points their rDNS to some unrelated FQDN hostname that does exist.) Ideally, I'd like to log both the IP and the name, but if I have to choose, I must have the raw IP.

I'm on CentOS 6 (in the process of upgrading to CentOS 7). Here is my `vsftpd.conf`, omitting comments:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is annoying, and I could not find a simple solution. I think the xferlog format is for backward compatibility with wu_ftp.

According to [fail2ban wiki](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Fail2ban:Community_Portal#Fail2ban_is_failing_to_ban_VSFTPD_bruteforce), this is what you need to do:

Configure VSFTP for "dual_log_enable=YES", and have fail2ban watch /var/log/vsftpd.log instead. This log file shows the incoming ip address instead of the DNS name.

What leaves me annoyed still though is the latency of looking up the reverse pointer, which relies on DNS lookup timeout. If transferring several thousand files and you have no reverse pointer, or no DNS server set for the in-addr block, will each transfer wait for DNS timeout?

Comment: Thanks! The dual_log_enable writes to vsftpd.log, which gives me log entries like this:

`Mon Mar 13 19:25:41 [pid 1] [Polycom] FAIL LOGIN: Client "141.xxx.xxx.xxx"`

which fail2ban can quite happily use to jail the miscreants.